# How to dynamically populate Highcharts column chart with two series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm straggling with two issues: 
The first - I'm trying to change this

```
series: [{
            type: 'column',
            color: '#a0a0a0',
            name: 'Previous',
            data: [A, B, C, D, E]

        }, {
            type: 'column',
            color: 'rgba(250,206,57,1)',
            name: 'Current',
            data: [AA, BB, CC, DD, EE]
        }
        ]
```

to populate with loop so the Number of items can be change, but this code made each item as a different series.

```
series: []

});

var newSeries = [];
for (var i = 2; i <= (N-1); i++) {
var newData = [];

var seria = {};
seria['name'] = 'Previous';
seria['data'] = [Pre[i]];
seria['color'] = '#2dbdda';

newSeries.push(seria);

var seria2 = {};
seria2['name'] = 'Current';
seria2['data'] = [Cur[i]];
seria2['color'] = '#214881';


newSeries.push(seria2);
```

}

What is wrong?

The second - how to add dynamically population to the X-Axis data label?

Thanx

Comment: Could you please give us more information how your Pre and Cur array looks like? What is your N number?

Comment: Cur[1] = 'A', Cur[2] = 'B' .... Cur[5] = 'E'. Pre[1]='AA', Pre[2]='BB" etc.

Comment: Yes, you are telling it to create a new series each time you loop through. You need to establish your series before looping, and only `push()` to the data array on each iteration.

Comment: The data is populate from database but to make it simple you can assume that Cur[1] = 'A', Cur[2] = 'B' .... Cur[5] = 'E'. Pre[1]='AA', Pre[2]='BB" etc. In this example N=5

Comment: Thank you, @jlbriggs Can you please post the correction you suggest? because I tried what I understood and it's not working for me.

Comment: See answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED based on updated question details**

OK, so, looking again at what you posted as your example data, your data is already in an array, so I am not seeing what needs a loop.

All you need to do is build your series in the chart options, and populate the `data` with the `Cur` and `Pre` arrays:

```
series: [{
  'name': 'Previous',
  'color': '#2dbdda',
  'data': Cur
}, {
  'name': 'Current',
  'color': '#214881',
  'data': Pre
}]
```

.

```
Cur[0] = 3
Cur[1] = 5
Cur[2] = 4
```

Is the same as

```
Cur = [3,5,4]
```

Simplified fiddle with no loop:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/qgv35fa8/1/

**Old answer here still, in case I've misunderstood what you're actually doing:**

The loop that currently have is explicitly generating a new series on each iteration.

If you have a set number of series, you need to create the series object separately, prior to looping through the data.

If you have a dynamic number of series, you will need a nested loop to build them.

Assuming that you are only looking at two series, and want the data to be dynamic, you can build the series first, and then loop through and populate the data, like this:

```
    //build the series placeholders, with empty data arrays
    var series = [{
            'name': 'Previous',
            'color': '#2dbdda',
            'data': []
        }, {
            'name': 'Current',
            'color': '#214881',
            'data': []
        }],
        Cur = [4, 5, 9, 8, 7], <-- example array; populate from your database
        Pre = [8, 6, 8, 1, 2];

    //loop through and push the data to your series data arrays
    for (var i = 0; i <= (Cur.length - 1); i++) {
        series[0].data.push([Pre[i]]);
        series[1].data.push([Cur[i]]);
    }
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/qgv35fa8/

Comment: Thank you @jlbriggs In your answer arrays Cur and are populate with a known number of items, how can I populate them in a loop?

Comment: Those arrays are just examples - those would be the dynamic arrays that you pull from your data source (the ` 
 
Cur[1] = 'A', Cur[2] = 'B' .... Cur[5] = 'E'. Pre[1]='AA', Pre[2]='BB"` etc) . The loop that follows is the loop that builds the actual series data.

Comment: Although, if your data is in the format that you posted, it is already an array and no loop is needed. Hold on while I update the answer...

Comment: Thank you again, but I did not explain my problem clearly.                          I need the loop because I use this charts to use unknown number of items (in my first simple example I show N=5). So I need a loop to populate the series array and the X axis data label array.

Comment: @SarahO. Right. But that doesn't matter. The `N` refers to the number of data points in the array. But you don't need to loop through them - you can just provide that array, as in my code above. All you do by looping through is say `data[0] = Cur[0]; data[1] = Cur[1]` etc, which is the same as saying `data = Cur`. Doesn't matter if there is one data point, or ten thousand data points.